# What is the proper way to earth aluminium profile frames?

Tags: safety, grounding

Frames built with aluminium profiles (such as 4040) do not make good electrical contacts at joints, because of the surface oxide protective layer.

[image: Aluminium profile frames]

What would be a good way to properly earth these frames? On my frame sits a heater which runs on 220V. It would be dangerous if cables loosen out and touch the frame.

Comment: Yes.  This is the rarely talked about issue with these types of extrusions.  I've raised this question with a couple of manufacturers.  Each did provide a method (accessory) to break the oxide layer at the joints.  You would need to do this **for every piece**.  I expect that very few people ever do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bore a hole slightly smaller than the screw, use a self-tapping screw, connect earthing cable to screw with cable lug.

Alternatively: there's ready-to-use slide-in terminals for exactly that purpose: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Abi-TyDWO4I

Generally, screwing up something with a *spring washer* that is guaranteed to penetrate the oxide layer should do the job.

Comment: The video was a bit unclear to me. Did he use a toothed lock washer to scratch the oxide layer, so that the slide-in terminal makes good electrical connection with the profile via the bolt?

Comment: yes, that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

[image] [image]

[Item International](http://item-international.com) have a variety of systems such as the straps on the left or the studs on the right. The latter, [Art. No.: 0.3.001.80](http://product.item24.ie/en/home/products/product-catalogue/productdetails/products/earthing-terminals/earthing-terminal-5-300180.html), for their Line 5 (5 mm slot profile) features

- T-Slot Nut 5 St M5, stainless
- Grub screw DIN 916-M5x16, St, stainless
- Hexagon nut M5
- Washer DIN 9021-5.3, brass
- Contact washer

The grub screw jacking off the slot-nut does the oxide penetration.

See also search on their site for [earth](http://product.item24.ie/en/nc/home/products/product-catalogue/product-search.html?tx_itemproducts_pi1[sword]=earth).